# Mapper file is not known to the MapperRegistry

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to show all the data in mysql database with mybatis on Spring Boot. However, the mapper.xml file is not known to the MapperRegistry.

I have tried changing the classpath of application.yaml.

application.yaml

```
mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:com/example/demo/repository/mybatis/*.xml
```

Shop Class

```
public class Shop {
    private String shopId;

    private String shopName;

    public Shop() {
        }

    public Shop(String shopId, String shopName) {
        this.shopId = shopId;
        this.shopName = shopName;
    }
}
```

ShopMapper.xml

```
    <!-- Mapping Shop Class to Shop tables -->
    <resultMap id="Shop"
               type="com.example.demo.domain.Shop">
        <id property="shopId" column="SHOP_ID"/>
        <result property="shopName" column="SHOP_NAME"/>
    </resultMap>


    <!-- Show all shops with the designated shopid -->
    <select id="get" resultMap="Shop">
        SELECT SHOP_ID, SHOP_NAME FROM SHOP
        WHERE SHOP_ID = #{shopId}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

ShopRepository

```
public Shop findOne(String shopId) {
    Shop shop = this.sqlSessionTemplate.getMapper(ShopMapper.class).get(shopId);
   return shop;
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
    public class PageController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/{shopId}", produces = "application/json")
    public Shop get(@PathVariable String shopId) {
        return this.service.get(shopId);
    }
}
```

Error:
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Type interface com.example.demo.repository.mybatis.ShopMapper is not known to the MapperRegistry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add a interface to match the ShopMapper.xml

```
@Mapper
public interface ShopMapper {
    Shop get(Long shopId);
}
```